# Prove that $\exp(\log(\frac{1}{1-x})) = \frac{1}{1-x}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, power-series, generating-functions

I am trying to prove this directly by comparing the coefficients in the two series rather than using formal calculus.

Here is what I have so far, but I think I made a mistake:

\begin{align*}
e^{\log\frac{1}{1-x}} &= \sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\log\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^n\\
&= 1+\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k\geq 1}\sum_{i_1+\dotsb+i_n=k}\frac{x^k}{i_1\dotsb i_n}
\end{align*}
Is this correct so far? If so, how do I proceed?

EDIT: \begin{align*}
\log\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) &= \sum_{k\geq1}\frac{x^k}{k}\\
e^x &= \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
The composition is well defined since the constant term of $\log(\frac{1}{1-x})$ is 0.

Comment: Well, that's obviously not going to work, because there needs to be a $x^0$ terms. The $k\geq 1$ only applies when $n\geq 1$.

Comment: I was afraid that I made a mistake, but can you explain that in more detail?

Comment: Tip: You can type `\log` instead of just `log` to properly format the logarithm function. This distinction is used to separate the operator $\log$ from the multiplication of the variables $l$, $o$, and $g$ or $log$. The same holds for `\sin`, `\cos`, and even ones like `\limsup`. The full list can be found [here](http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html).

Comment: To clarify the issue: for each $k\ge1$, one is trying to show that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{i_1+\dotsb+i_n=k}\frac1{i_1\dotsb i_n} =1.
$$

Comment: Are you required to use precisely this method?(Not that I have a non-trivial one working)

Comment: I am not required, but I think it will be nice to see how to prove that identity Greg posted works.

I have considered induction but it did not work nicely

Comment: First, note that the $t_i>0$, so you only need $$\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{t_1+\dots+t_k=k} \frac{1}{t_1\dots t_n} = 1$$

Comment: Or you could remove the outer sum as write it as: $$\sum_{t_1+\dots+t_n=k} \frac{1}{n!t_1\dots t_n} = 1$$ Then this looks like a probability measure on the space of all partitions of the integer $k$.

Comment: Did you mean on the space of all compositions of $k$? 
Thank you for your insight, it is a nice interpretation of the identity.

Answer (score 10):

I think everything is quite ok so far (besides maybe the index part, which could be written a little bit more rigidly). In order to show that

> \begin{align*}
> \exp\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}
> \end{align*}

we could proceed as follows:

> \begin{align*}
> \exp&\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\log\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^n\\
> &= 1+\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n!}\left(\sum_{i_1\geq 1}\frac{x^{i_1}}{i_1}\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot\left(\sum_{i_n\geq 1}\frac{x^{i_n}}{i_n}\right)\\
> &= 1+\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k\geq n}\sum_{{i_1+\ldots+i_n=k}\atop{i_1\geq 1,\ldots, i_n \geq 1}}\frac{x^k}{i_1\cdot\ldots\cdot i_n}\\
> &= 1+\sum_{k\ge1}x^k\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{{i_1+\ldots+i_n=k}\atop{i_1\geq 1,\ldots, i_n \geq 1}}\frac{1}{i_1\cdot\ldots\cdot i_n}\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}

Observe, the sums were exchanged in $(1)$.

To proceed conveniently, I will interchange the indices $n$ and $k$. We get

> \begin{align*}
> \exp&\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\right)\\
> &= 1+\sum_{n\ge1}x^n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{{i_1+\ldots+i_k=n}\atop{i_1\geq 1,\ldots, i_k \geq 1}}\frac{1}{i_1\cdot\ldots\cdot i_k}\tag{2}\\
> &= 1+\sum_{n\ge1}x^n\sum_{k=1}^{n}
> \sum_{{j_1+\ldots+j_n=k}\atop{{j_1+2j_2+\ldots+n j_n=n}\atop{j_1\geq 0,\ldots, j_n \geq 0}}}
> \frac{1}{j_1!1^{j_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot j_n!n^{j_n}}\tag{3}\\
> &= 1+\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}
> \sum_{{j_1+\ldots+j_n=k}\atop{{j_1+2j_2+\ldots+n j_n=n}\atop{j_1\geq 0,\ldots, j_n \geq 0}}}
> \frac{n!}{j_1!1^{j_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot j_n!n^{j_n}}\tag{4}\\
> &= 1+\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|s(n,k)|\tag{5}\\
> &= 1+\sum_{n\ge1}x^n\tag{6}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-x}
> \end{align*}

So, we have proved the question.

---

> *Some remarks to the transformations $(2)$ to $(6)$*
>
> Observe the *considerable change of index variables* in the step from $(2)$ to $(3)$.
>
> In $(2)$ there is with $1 \leq k \leq n$:
>   $$\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{{i_1+\ldots+i_k=n}\atop{i_1\geq 1,\ldots, i_k \geq 1}}\frac{1}{i_1\cdot\ldots\cdot i_k}$$
>   and so we sum up over *all compositions of $n$ containing exactly $k$ (non-negative) parts*, whereby *composition* means, that the order of parts matters.

Now we observe:

> In $(3)$ each composition $i_1+\ldots+i_k=n$ contains $j_1$ $1$s, $j_2$ $2$s, up to $j_n$, $n$s with $j_l \geq 0$. Since we consider a composition of $n$ we get
>   $$j_1 + 2 j_2 + \ldots + n j_n = n$$
>   Since the compositions under consideration contain *exactly $k$ summands* we get
>   $$j_1 + j_2 + \ldots + j_n = k$$
>   while the other $n-k$ summands are equal to $0$. Therefore we sum up
>   $$\sum_{{j_1+\ldots+j_n=k}\atop{{j_1+2j_2+\ldots+n j_n=n}\atop{j_1\geq 0,\ldots, j_n \geq 0}}}
> \frac{1}{j_1!1^{j_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot j_n!n^{j_n}}$$
>   Here, we again sum up over *all compositions of $n$ containing exactly $k$ (non-negative) parts*.

*Some gory details:* A factor $j_l!j_l^m$ in the denominator respects all compositions with $m$ summands of size $j_l$ . Since each of these $m$ summands corresponds to a factor in the denominator in $(2)$, we have therefore $j_l^m$ in the denominator of $(3)$. The numerator in $(2)$ divided by $k!$ gives the portion of all $k!$ permutations whereby interchange of equal summands is identified. In $(3)$ the same is done by respecting exactly the equal summands.

I think to better understand what's going on, it's instructive to see an example:

> Example for $n=5$ (corresponding to (2)):
>
> \begin{align*}
> k
> &\quad i_1+i_2+\cdots+i_k=5
> &a_k=\frac{1}{k!}& \left(\frac{1}{i_1\cdot\ldots\cdot i_k}\right)&5!a_k\\
> \hline\\
> 1&\quad5&\frac{1}{1!}&\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)&24\\
> 2&\quad1+4&\frac{1}{2!}&\left(\frac{2}{1\cdot4}\right)&30\\
> 2&\quad2+3&\frac{1}{2!}&\left(\frac{2}{2\cdot3}\right)&20\\
> 3&\quad1+1+3&\frac{1}{3!}&\left(\frac{3}{1\cdot1\cdot3}\right)&20\\
> 3&\quad1+2+2&\frac{1}{3!}&\left(\frac{3}{1\cdot2\cdot2}\right)&15\\
> 4&\quad1+1+1+2&\frac{1}{4!}&\left(\frac{4}{1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot2}\right)&10\\
> 5&\quad1+1+1+1+1&\frac{1}{5!}&\left(\frac{1}{1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1}\right)&1\\
> \end{align*}

Example for $n=5$ (corresponding to (3)):

> \begin{align*}
> k&\quad j_1+2j_2+3j_3+4j_4+5 j_5=5&b_k=&\frac{1}{j_1!1^{j_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot j_n!n^{j_n}}&5!b_k\\
> &\quad j_1+j_2+j_3+j_4+ j_5=k&&&\\
> \hline\\
> 1&\quad (0,0,0,0,1)&&\frac{1}{1!5^1}&24\\
> 2&\quad (1,0,0,1,0)&&\frac{1}{1!1^1 1!4^1}&30\\
> 2&\quad (0,1,1,0,0)&&\frac{1}{1!2^1 1!3^1}&20\\
> 3&\quad (2,0,1,0,0)&&\frac{1}{2!1^21!3^1}&20\\
> 3&\quad  (1,2,0,0,0)&&\frac{1}{1!1^1 2!2^2}&15\\
> 4&\quad  (3,1,0,0,0)&&\frac{1}{3!1^3 1!2^1}&10\\
> 5&\quad  (5,0,0,0,0)&&\frac{1}{5!1^5}&1\\
> \end{align*}

Observe, that the values $a_k$ and $b_k$ in each row coincide.

In $(3)$ the fraction is expanded by $n!$ to get a fine combinatorial interpretation in terms of *permutations* with corresponding *cycles*:

> According to section $6.2$ of *[Advanced Combinatorics](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/AdvancedComb.pdf)* from *Louis Comtet* we get the following definition and theorem:
>
> *Definition:* Let $j_1,j_2,\dots,j_n$ be integers $\geq 0$ such that:
>   $$j_1+2 j_2+\cdots+n j_n=n$$
>   A permutation $\sigma\in\mathcal{S}(N),|N|=n$ is said to be of type $(j_1,j_2,\dots,j_n)$ if its decomposition into disjoint cycles contains exactly $j_l$ cycles of length $l,l=1,2,3,\dots,n$.
>   And he proceeds (Theorem B):
>
> The number of permutations of type $(j_1,j_2,\dots,j_n)$ equals
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{n!}{j_1!1^{j_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot j_n!n^{j_n}}\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>
> Now observe, that we sum up  in $(4)$ over *all possible cycles over all lengths from $1\leq k \leq n$*, i.e. we sum up over *all $n!$* permutations, which results in the simplification in $(6)$.

The reason for introducing $s(n,k)$ in $(5)$ is presented in the rest of the answer.

> **Note:** When we are talking in $(7)$ about the number of permutations with certain cycle types we have to mention the important *Stirling numbers of the first kind*. In fact the whole question and answer is  permanently about these numbers and the *signless variant* of them. *Theorem D* in section $6.2$ from *[Advanced Combinatorics](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/AdvancedComb.pdf)* states:
>
> The number of permutation of $n$ whose decomposition has $k$ cycles equals the *unsigned Stirling number of the first kind* $|s(n,k)|$
>
> $$|s(n,k)|=\sum_{{j_1+\ldots+j_n=k}\atop{{j_1+2j_2+\ldots+n j_n=n}\atop{j_1\geq 0,\ldots, j_n \geq 0}}}
> \frac{n!}{j_1!1^{j_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot j_n!n^{j_n}}$$

See the corresponding entries for $|s(n,k)|$ from the example $n=5$:

> \begin{align*}
> k&\quad j_1+2j_2+3j_3+4j_4+5 j_5=5
> &&\frac{5!}{j_1!1^{j_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot j_n!n^{j_n}}&&|s(n,k)|\\
> &\quad j_1+j_2+j_3+j_4+ j_5=k&&\\
> \hline\\
> 1&\quad (0,0,0,0,1)&&24&&24\\
> 2&\quad (1,0,0,1,0)&&30&&50=30+20&\\
> 2&\quad (0,1,1,0,0)&&20&&&\\
> 3&\quad (2,0,1,0,0)&&20&&35=20+15&\\
> 3&\quad  (1,2,0,0,0)&&15&&&\\
> 4&\quad  (3,1,0,0,0)&&10&&10&\\
> 5&\quad  (5,0,0,0,0)&&1&&1&\\
> \end{align*}

To finally close the circle: Comtet presents in section $5.5$ the *double generating function* for $s(n,k)$, which is directly related to the expression $\exp(\log(\frac{1}{1-x}))$ of our question:

> A *double generating function* for the *Stirling Numbers of the first kind* is
>
> \begin{align*}
> \Psi(x,y)&=(1+x)^y\\
> &=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\sum_{k \geq 0}s(n,k)y^k\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
> &=1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}s(n,k)y^k\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
> \end{align*}

Since $(1+x)^y=\exp\left(y \log(1+x)\right)$ he presents as *vertical generating function* for $s(n,k)$:

> \begin{align*}
> \Psi_k(x,y)&=\sum_{n\geq k}s(n,k)\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
> &=\frac{1}{k!}\left(\log(1+x)\right)^k
> \end{align*}

It can be easily shown, that the *signless Stirling number of the first kind* are $|s(n,k)|=(-1)^{n-k}s(n,k)$. We have therefore according to our question:

> \begin{align*}
> \Psi(-x,-y)&=(1-x)^{-y}\\
> &=e^{y\log\frac{1}{1-x}}\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{y^k}{k!}\left(\log\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^k\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}y^k\Psi_k(-x,-y)\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq 0}y^k\sum_{n\geq k}|s(n,k)|\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
> \end{align*}

*Note:* Please note, that *much more* can be said about the *Stirling numbers of the first and second kind*. Comtet devotes a *whole chapter* exclusively to these numbers!

Answer (score 0):

A combinatorial proof.

Write $$-\log(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}x^n.$$

The $(n-1)!$ is the number of ways to seat people in a circle of size $n,$ where rotations are considered the same.

So:

$$(-1)^k\log^k(1-x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_{k,n}}{n!}x^n$$

Where $a_{k,n}$ is the number of ways to seat $n$ people around $k$ ordered circles, no table empty. You have $a_{0,0}=1,$ and $a_{k,n}=0$ for $k<n.$

Then $$\begin{align}\exp(-\log(1-x))&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=k}\frac{a_{k,n}}{n!}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_{k,n}}{k!}
\end{align} $$

So you need to prove:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_{k,n}}{k!}=n!\tag1$$ for all $n.$

Once you have that, you get:

$$\exp(-\log(1-x))=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}.$$

Now, $\frac{a_{k,n}}{k!}$ is the number of ways to arrange $n$ people around $k$ **unordered** circles.

So we want to find a way to map the set of all permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to the set of all ways to place $n$ people in an unordered set of circles, with any number of circles.

But when we write a permutation as cycles, that is just what we are doing. When $n=6,$ for example, the permutation $(123)(45)(6)$ can be thought of as putting 123 in that order, clockwise, around one circle, $45$ puts people $45$ in one circle, and $6$ sits alone at a circle.

---

The key is the combinatorial treatment of exponential generating functions, and what $f^n(x)$ means when $f(x)$ is a combinatorial generating function.

We can prove the combinatorial definition of $a_{k,n}$ by induction on $k.$ You just need the property that:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b_n}{n!}x^n\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{c_m}{m!}x^m=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!} \sum_{j=0}^n\binom nk b_jc_{n-j}$$

Then if $c_{n}=a_{k,n}$ and $b_n=(n-1)!$ (and $b_0=0.$) Then you get:

$$a_{k+1,n} =\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj b_ja_{k,n-j}\tag2$$

It is easy to see if $a_{k,n}$ is the number of ways to put $n$ people in $k$ ordered circles, the the sum on the right adds, for each $j,$ the number of ways of putting $j$ people around a first circle, times the number of ways of putting the remains people in $k$ circles.

---

There might be a non-combinatorial proof of $(1)$ directly from the recurrence $(2).$ I don't see it immediate, but it seems like some induction might work.