# Composition of formal power series of exp and log

Tags: combinatorics, logarithms, power-series, exponential-function

I'm considering the formal power series $$\exp(X)=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac 1 {n!} X^ n\in \mathbb Q [[X]]$$ and $$\log(1+X) =\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n} X^n\in \mathbb Q [[X]].$$
The composition of formal power series $f =\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n X^n$ and $g=\sum_{n\geq 1} b_n X^ n$ is defined as follows: For $k\geq 0$ the power series $g^k = \sum_l c_{k,l} X^ l$ is given by the Cauchy product. Note that $c_{k,l}=0$ if $k>l$ since $b_0=0$. Now $$f\circ g(X)=f(g(X)) := \sum_k a_k \sum_l c_{k,l} X^ l =  \sum _l \left(\sum_{k=0}^l a_k c_{k,l}\right) X^l.$$ How can I see that $\exp(\log(1+X))=1+X$ as formal power series only using reordering of terms?

I'm also interested in the other composition $\log(\exp(X))=X$ where $\log(\exp(X)=\log (1 + (\exp(X)-1))$ which is well-defined since the power series $\exp(X)-1$ has vanishing absolute term.

Comment: You are "interested"? In summing up a few definitions, or in own thoughts? The power series are well established, so if you really need the fact they are inverse as formal power series, share your insights, please!

Comment: [This questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/818839/177399) asks for a power-series-manipulation proof of $\exp\left(\log\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)\right)=\frac1{1-x}$. You can tweak that proof to get a solution for your problem; having $\log(1+x)$ instead of $\log(1/(1-x))$ introduces some extra negative signs.

Comment: This question takes care of your second question: [Proving $\log(e^x)=x$ with power series manipulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3326729/combinatorial-proof-that-the-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-are-inverse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this solution by modifying [episqrt163's excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825682/177399) giving a formal power series proof of $\exp(\log(\frac1{1-x}))=\frac1{1-x}$.
\begin{align}
\exp(\log(1+x))
  &=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{k!}\Big(\log(1+x)\Big)^k
\\&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac1{k!}\left(\sum_{i_1\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{i_1-1}x^{i_1}}{i_1}\right)\cdots\left(\sum_{i_k\ge 1}\frac{(-1)^{i_k-1}x^{i_k}}{i_k}\right)
\\&=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac1{k!}\sum_{n\ge k}\;
x^n\sum_{\substack{i_1+\dots+i_k=n \\ i_1\ge 1,\dots,i_k\ge 1}}
\frac{(-1)^{(i_1-1)+\dots+(i_k-1)}}{i_1 i_2\cdots i_k}
\\&=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\sum_{\substack{i_1+\dots+i_k=n \\ i_1\ge 1,\dots,i_k\ge 1}}\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{i_1 i_2\cdots i_k}
\end{align}
The innermost ranges over compositions of $n$ with exactly $k$ parts. To simplify this unwieldy summation, we will group together all compositions which correspond to the same unordered integer partition.

Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_k)$ be an integer partition of $n$ with exactly $k$ parts. Furthermore, define the multiplicity vector $(m_1,\dots,m_n)$ for $\lambda$, where for each $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, $m_i$ is the number of parts equal to $i$ in $\lambda$. The number of ordered compositions $(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ corresponding to $\lambda$ when put in sorted order is
$$
\frac{k!}{m_1!\cdots m_n!}
$$
This implies that we can re-index the summation to range over integer compositions $\lambda$ of $n$ with $k$ parts, as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\exp(\log(1+x))
  &= \sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}(-1)^{n-k}
\sum_{\substack{\lambda \,\vdash n \\ \text{len}(\lambda)=k}}
\frac{k!}{m_1!\cdots m_n!}\frac{1}{1^{m_1}\cdots n^{m_n}}
\\&= \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}
\sum_{\substack{\lambda \,\vdash n \\ \text{len}(\lambda)=k}}
\frac{n!}{m_1!1^{m_1}\cdots m_n!n^{m_n}}
\end{align}
$$
It is well known that $\frac{n!}{m_1!1^{m_1}\cdots m_n!n^{m_n}}$ is equal to the number of permutations with cycle type $\lambda$. Since we are summing over all $\lambda$ with $k$ parts, the innermost sum equals the number of permutations with exactly $k$ cycles, i.e. the unsigned Stirling number of the first kind. That is,
$$
\exp(\log(1+x))=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}{n \brack k}
$$
Finally, the alternating sum $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k}{n \brack k}$ is equal to zero for all $n\ge 2$, because it computes the difference between the number of permutations with an even number of cycles and the number of permutations with an  odd number of cycles. There is a bijection between these two groups, namely, multiplying by any transposition. The exception is $n=0$ and $n=1$, where $n$ is too small for a transposition to exists. In these cases, the difference is one. This exactly corresponds to the series
$$
1+x+\color{gray}{0x^2+0x^3+\dots},
$$
completing the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mixed proof where we use some combinatorics. Using
combinatorial classes as in *Analytic Combinatorics* by Flajolet and
Sedgewick we have the following class $\mathcal{P}$  of
permutations:

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\mathcal{P} = \textsc{SET}(\textsc{CYC}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

This says that permutations are sets of cycles (labeled enumeration).
Translating to EGFs we find

$$\frac{1}{1-z} = \exp \log\frac{1}{1-z}.$$

We seek $\frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + X$ which means we must FPS-substitute $z=X/(1+X)$
which is legal because there is no constant term in $X.$ We get

$$1+X = \exp\log(1+X).$$

We also have                                                                                                                             $$[X^0] \frac{1}{1-X/(1+X)} = 1$$                                                                                                                                 as well as for $n\ge 1$                                                                                                                                           $$[X^n] \frac{1}{1-X/(1+X)} =                                                    \sum_{q=1}^n [X^n] \frac{X^q}{(1+X)^q}                                           = \sum_{q=1}^n [X^{n-q}] \frac{1}{(1+X)^q}                                       \\ = \sum_{q=1}^n (-1)^{n-q} {n-1\choose q-1}                                    = (-1)^{n-1} \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} (-1)^q {n-1\choose q}                              = (-1)^{n-1} [[n=1]]$$                                                                                                                                            so we only have two non-zero terms, which are, $1+X.$

The above encapsulates the argument by Mike Earnest.

**Remark.** We can also prove equality of the two logarithmic terms
under the substitution. The labeled cycle EGF yields

$$\log\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{z^q}{q}.$$

Do the substitution to get

$$\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{1}{q} \frac{X^q}{(1+X)^q}.$$

What is the coefficient on $[X^n]$ (constant coefficient is zero)?

$$\sum_{q=1}^n \frac{1}{q} [X^{n-q}] \frac{1}{(1+X)^q}
= \sum_{q=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{n-q}}{q} {n-1\choose q-1}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \sum_{q=1}^n (-1)^q {n\choose q}
= \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}.$$

This is precisely the definition that was given by OP.

We also have that the labeled set EGF is

$$\exp(z) = \sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{z^q}{q!}$$

because there is one set containing $q$ labeled elements.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but longer than a comment:

You could consider formal power series with a parameter

$$\exp_t(x) = (1+t x)^{\frac{1}{t}}$$

and

$$\log_t(1+x) = \frac{(1+x)^t - 1}{t}$$

and check that

$$\exp_t( \log_t(1+x)) = 1+x$$

(formally), so true for $t=0$ also.  What gives?  We are using

$$((1+x)^t)^{\frac{1}{t}} = 1+x$$

a composition of power series.  So perhaps one should also elucidate

$$((1+x)^a)^b = (1+x)^{a\cdot b}$$

$\bf{Added:}$ The above composition of series is equivalent to the equality

$$\sum_{m_1 + 2 m_2 + 3 m_3 + \cdots = n} \frac{(\sum_{i\ge 1} m_i)!}{\prod_{i\ge 1} m_i!} \binom{b}{\sum_i m_i} \prod_{i\ge 1} \binom{a}{i}^{m_i} = \binom{a b}{n}$$